# Protocol Error in accessing Office 365 Sharepoint list using C# application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, console, sharepoint-online

Getting below error when trying to access sharepoint data from WebService
Additional information: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

1. Status is showing as - ProtocolError
2. Inner exception - null Response
3. Status Code - Unauthorized

Able to access sharepoint directly from browser with same credentials
Code:

```
            App.ClientSpecsList.Lists listService = new App.ClientSpecsList.Lists();

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
//Tried setting different protocol types
            listService.Url = "https://testsite.sharepoint.com/TrainingForAll/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
            listService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password, "Domain");

            System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = listService.GetListAndView("Client Specs","");
            string strListID = ndListView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
            string strViewID = ndListView.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["Name"].Value;
```

The same code was working fine with SharePoint 2008

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below, make sure the username, password and domainname are right.

```
App.ClientSpecsList.Lists listService = new App.ClientSpecsList.Lists();
listService.Url = "http://sp2013/sites/team/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
listService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainname");
System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = listService.GetListAndView("Client Specs", "");
string strListID = ndListView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
string strViewID = ndListView.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["Name"].Value;
```

If still get the 401 error, try to use admin user to check if it works. And check steps in the article below.

[SharePoint 2010 - Web Services](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-web-services/)

If you want to access SharePoint Online, we need use the [SharePointOnlineCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj164693(v%3Doffice.15)) class to pass credentials.